# Closed and bounded subsets are compact.

Tags: general-topology

I was reading the proof from here http://planetmath.org/proofofheineboreltheorem, and I was confused at the end when they used Tychonoff's Theorem. After we show that a closed interval is compact, doesn't Tychonoff's theorem obviously imply the case for $n > 1$? I'm not sure why the proof mentions the norm topology to complete the proof.

In other words, if we know that $[a,b]$ for all $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$ is compact, don't we immediatly get that $[a_1, b_1] \times [a_2, b_2] \times ... \times [a_n, b_n]$ is compact by using Tychonoff's theorem?

Comment: You need to see that the norm topology (presumably induced by the Euclidean norm) is in fact the product topology to invoke Tikhonov's theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately you want to show that $[a_1,b_1]\times ... \times [a_n,b_n]$ is compact **as a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$**, that is with respect to the subspace topology induced from the standard topology on $\mathbb R^n$.

Tychonoff's theorem considers $[a_1,b_1]\times ... \times [a_n,b_n]$ with the **product topology**. So in order to complete the proof you have to show that these two topologies coincide (in this case).